# How to plot coordinates on a spherical shape file correctly?

Tags: r, geospatial, shapefile, r-sf

So I'm trying to plot a bunch of coordinates on the earth and track how many coordinates are in each country. I have plotted the map and coordinates fine, but when I try to use the intersection to count how many coordinates fall within each country (polygon) it results in error. I've tried using the st_make_valid function to fix the earth shape file but it messes up the geometry. I'm new to using R so any help would be greatly appreciated.

I have used the following code to plot the earth shape file and the coordinates on top:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
library(rmapshaper)
library(rnaturalearth)
library(rnaturalearthdata)
library(sp)
library(raster)

###############

# Load Data

###############

# Read in data from .csv file

MeteoriteData <- read.csv("C:/Users/ChaseDickson_/Desktop/College/AERO 689/Semester Project/Meteorite Landings.csv")

# Convert these points to an SF object, specifying the X and Y

#  column names, and supplying the CRS as 4326 (which is WGS84)

MeteoriteData.sf <- st_as_sf(MeteoriteData, coords=c('long', 'lat'), crs=4326)

world <- (ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf"))

MeteoriteMap <- ggplot(data = world) +
  geom_sf() +
  geom_sf(data = MeteoriteData.sf, size = 0.5, shape = 23, fill = "darkred") +
  theme_bw()

MeteoriteMap
```

Which gives the following plot

[image]

However, when getting the intersection of the code I used this

`intersection <- st_intersection(x = world, y = MeteoriteData.sf)`

But it gave the error

```
Error in wk_handle.wk_wkb(wkb, s2_geography_writer(oriented = oriented,  : 
  Loop 96 is not valid: Edge 743 crosses edge 998
```

To fix this I changed the world sf by adding st_make_valid like so:

`world <- st_make_valid(ne_countries(scale = "small", returnclass = "sf"))`

Now this allows the intersection function to work as such:

```
intersection <- st_intersection(x = world, y = MeteoriteData.sf)

int_result <- intersection %>%
  group_by(sovereignt) %>%
  count()
```

And the output is recorded shown below

[image]

However, this messes the countries (polygons) up in the plot and will give inaccurate data as the new earth shape file is shown below:

[image]

Any help figuring out how to maintain the first plot, but still get the intersection function and count to work after adding st_make_valid would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `{rnaturalearth}` package has had a long and productive history, but - kind of like the similar `{maps}` package - it belongs to a different, less demanding era. You should consider doing a Marie Kondo on it: thank it for its service, and let it go.

So instead of trying to repair its failings look for a different instance of world dataset, which is a very common and thus standardized use case.

Consider this piece of code, and note that it is not a single piece of wrong geometry, but 6 (out of 241). Correcting them one by one would be a fruitless task.

```
library(sf)

rnaturalearth::ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")|>
  st_is_valid() |>
  table()

# FALSE  TRUE 
#     6   235
```

My preferred source of the world country data is the `{giscoR}` package, which interfaces GISCO spatial dataset, ultimately maintained by Eurostat.

It is very handy, known to be valid and actively maintained.

```
giscoR::gisco_get_countries(resolution = "20") |>
  st_is_valid() |>
  table()

# TRUE 
#  257
```

The rest of your code - the intersection and plotting part - should work just fine once you get rid of invalid geometries.

Comment: what a beautiful answer lol!

Answer (score 2):

Just a note regarding `st_intersection()` (and shamelessly building on top of Jindra's answer.. ) -
this happens to be an extremely expensive method to retrieve hit count, especially if resulting geometries are just a by-product that will be disregarded (and it's expensive for this too, check `st_join()`)

For counting you can save *a lot* (like ~250ms vs ~16s(**!**) for 100 random points on my machine) by opting for `st_intersects()`:

```r
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)
countries <-  giscoR::gisco_get_countries(resolution = "20")

set.seed(1)
random_points <- data.frame(x = runif(100,-180,180), y = runif(100,-90,90)) |> 
  st_as_sf(coords = c("x","y"), crs = "WGS84")

#> Measure st_intersection():
system.time({
  countries_isect <- st_intersection(countries, random_points)
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>   15.97    0.47   16.50

#> Measure st_intersects():
system.time({
  countries$hits <- lengths(st_intersects(countries, random_points))
})
#>    user  system elapsed 
#>    0.22    0.00    0.22

ggplot(countries) +
  geom_sf(data = countries) +
  geom_sf(data = random_points) +
  theme_void()
```

Results, i.e. non-zero `lengths(st_intersects(countries, random_points))`:

```
countries[countries$hits > 0,c("NAME_ENGL","hits")] |> st_drop_geometry()
#>              NAME_ENGL hits
#> 4           Antarctica    7
#> 13           Australia    1
#> 30              Brazil    4
#> 31               China    3
#> 48           Greenland    1
#> 55              Canada    3
#> 116         Kazakhstan    1
#> 117               Laos    1
#> 125           Cambodia    1
#> 141         Mauritania    1
#> 155               Oman    1
#> 162           Paraguay    1
#> 184               Mali    1
#> 185 Russian Federation    5
#> 221      United States    3
#> 223          Venezuela    1
#> 249           Thailand    1
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-11-23 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>