# Closed boundaries on a map when using geom_sf to cross dateline

Tags: r, ggplot2, maps, coordinate-systems, geom-sf

I am trying to make a Robinson-projection map that is *not* centered at longitude 0, and crosses both sides of the 180° line.

My code is below:

```
library("rnaturalearthdata")
world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf")
robinson = "+proj=robin +lon_0=-90 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"
transformed = st_transform(world, robinson)
ggplot(data=transformed) + geom_sf(fill = "gray", colour = "black")+theme_bw()
```

That generates this map, which is oriented correctly, except all the split boundaries are "inside out" and wrap across the whole map.

[image]

There is this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32591368/pacific-centric-robinson-projection-with-ggplot-in-r?rq=4) from 9 years ago, but I am hoping that with recent package updates, there is a less complicated solution, which will allow us to plot our lat/lon data-points using `geom_point()` without additional transformations.

EDIT #2: The solution by L. Tyrone works great for me. To plot points using this method, you will have to transform them from a data frame to an sf object with the same Coord Ref System, or else the lat/lon is interpreted as meters, and ends up indistinguishable from 0,0:

```
# Transform with fake data...
fakedata=data.frame(lat=c(-10,-20,80),lon=c(45,-100,120),tag=c("indian","tropical","arctic"))
transpoint = st_as_sf(fakedata,coords=c("lon","lat"),crs=4326)
dtran = st_transform(transpoint,robinson)
```

Then you can plot them by adding the special `geometry=` and `stat=` declarations to `geom_point` or even `geom_text_repel`:

```
geom_point(data=dtran,aes(geometry=geometry,color=tag),stat="sf_coordinates") +
geom_text_repel(data=dtran,aes(geometry=geometry,label=tag),stat="sf_coordinates")
```

Final Result:
[image: successful plot of fake data onto map]

Comment: Have a look on this https://stackoverflow.com/a/74528874/17486894

Comment: Thanks Grzegorz. I tried the gisco library but no difference in the output.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to 'break' any polygons that cross 180 prior to projecting them. The `st_break_antimeridian()` function from the `sf` package is the easiest way to achieve this. It will throw a warning, which you can safely ignore.

```
library(rnaturalearth)
library(sf)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

world <- ne_countries(scale = "medium", returnclass = "sf") %>%
  st_set_crs(4326)

robinson <- "+proj=robin +lon_0=-90 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"

world_robinson_90w <- world %>%
  st_break_antimeridian(lon_0 = -90) %>%
  st_transform(crs = robinson)

ggplot() +
  geom_sf(data = world_robinson_90w)
```

[image: result]

Comment: This is a miracle. Thank you so much. You don't know how long I've struggled with this. I had to update my `sf` to get the break antimeridian function, but it is working and I can even plot transformed points.

Comment: @beroe - gosh, a bounty will be lovely too. And I know how long you struggled with this because I was you not that long ago :)